# Focus the textbox by detecting CTRL+A key in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, textbox

Please find the below code for more information.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Autosearch</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="autosuggest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="suggestion.js"></script>

<style>
#txtbox{color:Black; width:200px};
</style>
</head>

<body>
   <p>search</p>
    <p><input type="text" id="txtbox" /></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var textbox = new AutoSuggestControl
(document.getElementById("txtbox"),suggestions);        
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**json object:**

```
suggestions= {
keyword : 
[
{child1:'Pay who? How Much? When?', child2:' who?'},
{child1:'Balance', child2:'type?'},
{child1:'Beneficiary', child2:'add'},
{child1:'Change Passcode'},
{child1:'Change Memorable Word'}
]
};
```

**javascript file:**

```
function AutoSuggestControl(textbox,suggestions) {
this.textbox=textbox;
this.suggestions=suggestions;   
var caretpos=0;
init();


function requestsuggestion(AutoSuggestControl){
    console.log("requestsuggestion");
    var This=this;
    var suggestedvalue = [];
    caretpos=textbox.selectionStart;
    if(textbox.selectionStart || textbox.selectionStart == '0')
    var temptextboxval=textbox.value.substr(0,caretpos);
    if(temptextboxval.length > 0)   
    {

        for (var i=0; i < This.suggestions.keyword.length; i++) {
if
(suggestions.
keyword[i].   
child1.toLowerCase().indexOf                     
(temptextboxval.toLowerCase ()  ) == 0) 
{   
            suggestedvalue.push(This.suggestions.keyword[i].child1); 
            console.log(suggestions.keyword[i].child1);
        }
        }
    }

    function autosuggest() {
    if(suggestedvalue.length > 0){
        typeAhead(suggestedvalue[0]);
    console.log(suggestedvalue[0]);
    }
    else{
        textbox.value=temptextboxval;
    }

}

function typeAhead(suggestedvalue) {

    if (textbox.createTextRange || textbox.setSelectionRange)
    {
        var txtLen=caretpos;
        textbox.value=suggestedvalue;
        setCaretPosition(txtLen,suggestedvalue.length);
    }

}

function setCaretPosition(txtLen,sugLen){

    if (textbox.createTextRange) 
    {
    var oRange = textbox.createTextRange(); 
    oRange.moveStart("character", sugLen); 
    oRange.moveEnd("character", txtLen - textbox.value.length);  

    oRange.select();


//use setSelectionRange() for Mozilla
    } 
    else if (textbox.setSelectionRange) 
    {
        textbox.setSelectionRange(sugLen,txtLen);


    }
    //this.lastCaret=txtLen;

//set focus back to the textbox
textbox.focus();  
}

autosuggest();
}


function init() {
    var oThis = this;
    //assign the onkeyup event handler
    textbox.onkeyup = function (event) {
    //check for the proper location of the event object
    if (!event) {
      event = window.event;


    }    
    console.log(textbox);
    //call the handleKeyUp() method with the event object
    handleKeyUp(event);


};
}

function handleKeyUp(event) {
    var e=event;
    var stay=0;
    var iKeyCode = event.keyCode;

    document.onkeydown=function(e){
        if(iKeyCode==65 && e.ctrlKey)
        {stay=1;
    }
    console.log("stay"+stay);
    if(stay==1)
    textbox.focus();
    else
    requestsuggestion(AutoSuggestControl); 

}
}
```

I'm creating a autosuggest text box, but when I press `ctrl+A` key the textbox becomes blank. It should focus the text box while retaining the cursor position. Please help me out.

Thank you in adavnce.

Answer (score 0):

When you click Ctrl+A,

```
if(iKeyCode==65 && e.ctrlKey)
{
    //this block does not work , because you will click first Ctrl, then A(65)
    stay=1;
}
```

I think You must change && to ||(or).

Comment: I have already tried that, but then if you type "a" normally then also that condition will be satisfied and it would cause unwanted result. like when you want to type "pay".  I also want to change the color of the yet to type suggested strings. any ideas on that? how to do that. except focus().